# Why is the Batch script I created to convert MP4 files to GIF files with FFmpeg not working?

Tags: ffmpeg, batch, conversion, mp4, gif

This is what I have so far. It runs, but throws an error.

I have come up with the following below.

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -t 3 -vf "fps=10, scale=320, flags=lanczos, split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -loop 0 copy "__newfiles\%%~na.gif"
```

Comment: “…but throwing an error.” What error?

Answer (score 1):

### Unable to find a suitable output format for 'copy'

Remove `copy`. That's not an actual option. `ffmpeg` is assuming you want the output to be named `copy`, but it doesn't know what container format (GIF, MP4, AVI, MKV, MOV, etc) `copy` is supposed to be.

### Invalid size '320'

Change `scale=320` to `scale=320:-1`. You need to provide both width and height. The `-1` means to automatically choose the correct height. See the [scale filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale).

### No such filter: 'flags'

`flags` is not a standalone filter. It is an option for the scale filter. Change `scale=320:-1, flags=lanczos` to `scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos`. See the [scale filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale).

---

### Fixed command

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -t 3 -vf "fps=10, scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos, split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -loop 0 "__newfiles\%%~na.gif"
```

Comment: You're awesome thank you!

Comment: @ChristopherShaw  Feel free to say thanks in the way that the platform operates, I mean, applying your "accepted" in this answer. See the **[tour](https://superuser.com/tour)**